# OnClick not working on iOS when the clicked elements is doing a POST for a form on the same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

On iOS (iPhone for example), I try to POST a form to the same tab, by clicking on submit. I want at the same time of clicking the submit, to trigger a JS event with OnClick.

For example, to append `snippet.htm`

In my server logs I can see that the snippet is not called if the form is set to open in the same tab, but only on new tab. In other devices such as desktop pc, it works as expected.

```
<h1>POST - new tab - snippet is called</h1>
<form action="/go.php" target="_blank" method="post" class="con">
  <input type="hidden"  name="go" value="foo"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<h1>POST - same tab - snippet is NOT called on iOS</h1>
<form action="/go.php" target="_self" method="post" class="con">
  <input type="hidden"  name="go" value="foo"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".con").on("click",function(){var t=document.createElement("iframe");t.style.width="0px",t.style.height="0px",t.style.display="block",document.body.appendChild(t),t.src="/snippet.htm?"});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the point of appending a "snippet" to a page you're about to leave?

Comment: @Bergi the snippet is for tracking conversion. the user is leaving the page since he clicked a link I wanted him to click. So I want to track it as conversion. to do so, I want to use this event.

Comment: the snippet contains tracking code of a third party platform, for example.

Comment: Track it on the `go.php` page then? Or use [`.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) instead of an iframe.

Comment: to do this in `go.php` might work for the snippet, but another case I have is also to write into my own database info that includes meta-info about the click. this meta info exists in-line in the original page, like `TrackEvent(Price:500, User:Joe)` and so on. I don't have a good way to generate this info in the go page.  Someone suggested me sendBeacon but it was the first time I heard about it. So before I'll look for a developer who knows how to use it, I'm trying to see if there is a more simple solution

Comment: Just send that as a parameter (`?track_price=500&track_user=Joe`, or other hidden inputs that the script can fill) to the php server script

Comment: the actual string is very textual, it can be 150 to 250 characters. I don't think it will be a good practice to pass such long string as a parameter. also, I already have this working for all devices except iOS on same tab, so I'd rather not change the whole logic just for the sake of this issue.